# What is wrong with this junction command?

Tags: windows-8, junction

I want to make a junction: `junction.exe c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0 d:\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0`

Every time I try, I get the [same three junction usage tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCt3P.jpg). I am using Windows 8, and running cmd under administrator privileges, and have removed the `read only` checkbox from the `program files (x86)` folder. When I type `junction.exe c:\link c:\link2` it works like a charm. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a quick oversight. Nothing major.

When using Spaces like " " in Commands, you must put them in quotation marks otherwise the system reads it as a new line (or some such).

Here is the command you need;

```
junction.exe "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" "d:\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0"
```

As you can see each file path is encapsulated with Quotations making it read as 1 line.

You should be good to go now dude!

Comment: You are right about using quotation marks, but not about the spaces in commands- it's the spaces in the address paths that require quotations, which would explain why my other example (see question) works. I will accept this answer, but you should edit it, I think. Thanks.